# Would like to use VBA to list Built-in functions

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I would like to, programmatically, using VBA, generate a list (text, table, does not matter) of VBA functions available in an Access file. I am NOT looking to generate a list of user-written functions . . . I am looking to generate a list of built-in functions. I would be looking to generate a list, something like this:

left,instr,date,mid,asc,reverse,month,cstr, etc., etc., etc.

I you look in the VBA Object Browser, there are whole collections of VBA commands under the class names of Conversion, DateTime, FileSystem, Financial, Information, Interaction, Math and Strings.

I've tried all kinds of object declarations in VBA trying to enumerate these classes, and have not been successful. All I want to be able to do is to enumerate the function names.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to locate such a list in the documentation rather than programmatically pulling it from the Object Browser? If they are not user defined then they are documented.

Comment: What you're asking for is basically a `TypeLib` reader, and while they aren't difficult to implement, they aren't trivial either (I've done extensive work on the [Rubberduck add-in's reader](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/tree/next/Rubberduck.Parsing/ComReflection)).  If you're good reading them from an XML file, we [have serialized versions in our test library here](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/tree/next/RubberduckTests/Testfiles/Resolver).

Comment: Try something like: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5180/RunTime-COM-Object-Inspection

Answer (score 4):

The current version of [Rubberduck](http://www.rubberduckvba.com/) (2.0.12, not yet released - scheduled for early February) gets the COM API working again (2.0.11 broke it), so if you can build the current version ("next" branch, using Visual Studio) ...or wait for 2.0.12, you can reference Rubberduck's type library and write VBA code like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ListAllLoadedDeclarations()
    Dim ducky As Rubberduck.ParserState
    Set ducky = New Rubberduck.ParserState
    ducky.Initialize Application.VBE
    ducky.Parse

    Dim item As Variant
    Dim typedItem As Rubberduck.Declaration

    For Each item In ducky.AllDeclarations
        Set typedItem = item
        If typedItem.DeclarationType = DeclarationType_Function _
            Or typedItem.DeclarationType = DeclarationType_Procedure _
            Or typedItem.DeclarationType = DeclarationType_PropertyGet _
            Or typedItem.DeclarationType = DeclarationType_PropertyLet _
            Or typedItem.DeclarationType = DeclarationType_PropertySet _
        Then
            ' Project.Module.Member
            Debug.Print typedItem.ParentDeclaration.ParentDeclaration.Name & "." & _
                        typedItem.ParentDeclaration.Name & "." & _
                        typedItem.Name & " (" & DeclarationTypeName(typedItem.DeclarationType) & ")"
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Private Function DeclarationTypeName(ByVal value As Rubberduck.DeclarationType) As String
    Select Case value
        Case DeclarationType_Function
            DeclarationTypeName = "Function"
        Case DeclarationType_Procedure
            DeclarationTypeName = "Sub"
        Case DeclarationType_PropertyGet
            DeclarationTypeName = "Property Get"
        Case DeclarationType_PropertyLet
            DeclarationTypeName = "Property Let"
        Case DeclarationType_PropertySet
            DeclarationTypeName = "Property Set"
    End Select
End Function
```

This will list ALL `Sub`, `Function` and `Property` members in ALL early-bound references (including all the "user code" in the VBE), printing them to the *immediate pane* (you'll want to change `Debug.Print` to write to a file, perhaps), looking something like this (here in an Excel project):

```
(snip)
Excel.PivotTable.Name (Property Let)
Excel.PivotTable.ViewCalculatedMembers (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.SourceData (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.InGridDropZones (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.GrandTotalName (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.Update (Sub)
Excel.PivotTable.SmallGrid (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.EnableWriteback (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.Version (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.ShowCellBackgroundFromOLAP (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.RowRange (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.CalculatedFields (Function)
Excel.PivotTable.AllocateChanges (Sub)
Excel.PivotTable.AllocationValue (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.DisplayMemberPropertyTooltips (Property Let)
Excel.PivotTable.CacheIndex (Property Let)
Excel.PivotTable.CompactRowIndent (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.DiscardChanges (Sub)
Excel.PivotTable.EnableDrilldown (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.AlternativeText (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.DataLabelRange (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.ListFormulas (Sub)
Excel.PivotTable.AllowMultipleFilters (Property Let)
Excel.PivotTable.RowAxisLayout (Sub)
Excel.PivotTable.ShowTableStyleColumnHeaders (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.Tag (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.LayoutRowDefault (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.DataPivotField (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.TableStyle (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.DisplayNullString (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.PageRange (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.CalculatedMembersInFilters (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.ShowPageMultipleItemLabel (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.Summary (Property Let)
Excel.PivotTable.DisplayFieldCaptions (Property Let)
Excel.PivotTable.ChangePivotCache (Sub)
Excel.PivotTable.ShowTableStyleRowStripes (Property Let)
Excel.PivotTable.EnableWizard (Property Let)
Excel.PivotTable.PageFields (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.PageFieldOrder (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.PrintTitles (Property Let)
Excel.PivotTable.SubtotalHiddenPageItems (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.VisualTotalsForSets (Property Let)
Excel.PivotTable.ShowTableStyleRowHeaders (Property Let)
Excel.PivotTable.PivotSelectionStandard (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.AddFields (Function)
Excel.PivotTable.CompactLayoutRowHeader (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.RepeatItemsOnEachPrintedPage (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.AllocationMethod (Property Let)
Excel.PivotTable.VacatedStyle (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.Value (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.GetPivotData (Function)
Excel.PivotTable.InnerDetail (Property Let)
Excel.PivotTable.Format (Sub)
Excel.PivotTable.PageFieldStyle (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.SubtotalLocation (Sub)
Excel.PivotTable.ShowPages (Function)
Excel.PivotTable.ShowValuesRow (Property Let)
Excel.PivotTable.MDX (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.DataBodyRange (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.PreserveFormatting (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.DisplayContextTooltips (Property Let)
Excel.PivotTable.ChangeList (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.Location (Property Let)
Excel.PivotTable.PivotSelection (Property Let)
Excel.PivotTable.RefreshDate (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.VisibleFields (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.MergeLabels (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.EnableDataValueEditing (Property Let)
Excel.PivotTable.TableRange1 (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.ShowDrillIndicators (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.Allocation (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.Parent (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.DisplayImmediateItems (Property Let)
Excel.PivotTable.HasAutoFormat (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.PageFieldWrapCount (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.EnableFieldDialog (Property Let)
Excel.PivotTable.RepeatAllLabels (Sub)
Excel.PivotTable.VisualTotals (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.DisplayEmptyColumn (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.CubeFields (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.ShowTableStyleLastColumn (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.PivotTableWizard (Sub)
Excel.PivotTable.PageRangeCells (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.DisplayErrorString (Property Let)
Excel.PivotTable.RowGrand (Property Let)
Excel.PivotTable.SortUsingCustomLists (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable._Default (Property Let)
Excel.PivotTable.ColumnGrand (Property Let)
Excel.PivotTable.CalculatedMembers (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.Application (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.ShowTableStyleColumnStripes (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.PivotColumnAxis (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.NullString (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.Slicers (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.ErrorString (Property Let)
Excel.PivotTable.AllocationWeightExpression (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.DisplayEmptyRow (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.SaveData (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.EnableFieldList (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.SelectionMode (Property Let)
Excel.PivotTable.FieldListSortAscending (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.RefreshDataSourceValues (Sub)
Excel.PivotTable.ViewCalculatedMembers (Property Let)
Excel.PivotTable.SourceData (Property Let)
Excel.PivotTable.TableStyle2 (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.CommitChanges (Sub)
Excel.PivotTable.InGridDropZones (Property Let)
Excel.PivotTable.GrandTotalName (Property Let)
Excel.PivotTable.TotalsAnnotation (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.CompactLayoutColumnHeader (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.PrintDrillIndicators (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.SmallGrid (Property Let)
Excel.PivotTable.EnableWriteback (Property Let)
Excel.PivotTable.ManualUpdate (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.Name (Property Get)
Excel.PivotTable.ShowCellBackgroundFromOLAP (Property Let)
Excel.IFont.TintAndShade (Property Let)
Excel.IFont.Creator (Property Get)
Excel.IFont.ThemeColor (Property Get)
Excel.IFont.Size (Property Get)
Excel.IFont.Italic (Property Get)
Excel.IFont.Strikethrough (Property Get)
Excel.IFont.FontStyle (Property Get)
Excel.IFont.Parent (Property Get)
Excel.IFont.Color (Property Get)
Excel.IFont.Name (Property Get)
Excel.IFont.OutlineFont (Property Get)
Excel.IFont.Application (Property Get)
Excel.IFont.Underline (Property Get)
Excel.IFont.ThemeColor (Property Let)
Excel.IFont.Size (Property Let)
Excel.IFont.Italic (Property Let)
Excel.IFont.Strikethrough (Property Let)
Excel.IFont.FontStyle (Property Let)
Excel.IFont.ThemeFont (Property Get)
Excel.IFont.Color (Property Let)
Excel.IFont.Name (Property Let)
Excel.IFont.OutlineFont (Property Let)
Excel.IFont.Underline (Property Let)
Excel.IFont.Shadow (Property Get)
Excel.IFont.ThemeFont (Property Let)
Excel.IFont.Superscript (Property Get)
Excel.IFont.Subscript (Property Get)
Excel.IFont.ColorIndex (Property Get)
Excel.IFont.Shadow (Property Let)
Excel.IFont.Superscript (Property Let)
Excel.IFont.Subscript (Property Let)
Excel.IFont.Bold (Property Get)
Excel.IFont.ColorIndex (Property Let)
Excel.IFont.Background (Property Get)
Excel.IFont.Bold (Property Let)
Excel.IFont.TintAndShade (Property Get)
Excel.IFont.Background (Property Let)
Rubberduck._Extension.OnBeginShutdown (Sub)
Rubberduck._Extension.OnConnection (Sub)
Rubberduck._Extension.OnStartupComplete (Sub)
Rubberduck._Extension.ToString (Property Get)
Rubberduck._Extension.OnAddInsUpdate (Sub)
Rubberduck._Extension.GetHashCode (Function)
Rubberduck._Extension.OnDisconnection (Sub)
Rubberduck._Extension.GetType (Function)
Rubberduck._Extension.Equals (Function)
Excel.IPivotLines.Application (Property Get)
Excel.IPivotLines.Parent (Property Get)
Excel.IPivotLines.Creator (Property Get)
Excel.IPivotLines.Item (Property Get)
Excel.IPivotLines.Count (Property Get)
Excel.IPivotLines._NewEnum (Property Get)
Excel.IPivotLines._Default (Property Get)
Office.ICTPFactory.CreateCTP (Function)
Office.IRibbonControl.Tag (Property Get)
Office.IRibbonControl.Context (Property Get)
Office.IRibbonControl.Id (Property Get)
Office.FoundFiles.Application (Property Get)
Office.FoundFiles.Count (Property Get)
Office.FoundFiles.Creator (Property Get)
Office.FoundFiles._NewEnum (Property Get)
Office.FoundFiles.Item (Property Get)
Office.PickerDialog.Creator (Property Get)
Office.PickerDialog.CreatePickerResults (Function)
Office.PickerDialog.Resolve (Function)
Office.PickerDialog.Title (Property Let)
Office.PickerDialog.Show (Function)
Office.PickerDialog.Title (Property Get)
Office.PickerDialog.DataHandlerId (Property Let)
Office.PickerDialog.Properties (Property Get)
Office.PickerDialog.Application (Property Get)
Office.PickerDialog.DataHandlerId (Property Get)
Excel.Menu.Enabled (Property Let)
Excel.Menu.MenuItems (Property Get)
Excel.Menu.Enabled (Property Get)
Excel.Menu.Delete (Sub)
Excel.Menu.Parent (Property Get)
Excel.Menu.Caption (Property Let)
Excel.Menu.Index (Property Get)
Excel.Menu.Caption (Property Get)
Excel.Menu.Creator (Property Get)
Excel.Menu.Application (Property Get)
```

Note that this includes hidden members, and Rubberduck knows about the return types, parameters and visibility as well, but the API currently makes it a bit hard to efficiently query things.

Rubberduck's COM API is still an experimental feature, subject to major changes and VERY open to suggestions and feature requests, so I wouldn't recommend using it in any production code - but playing with it can certainly get you somewhere much faster than by scraping MSDN or writing your own COM type library reader / reflector.

---

Since we serialize this information to XML so that our tests and the website's "try code inspections" feature can work outside the VBE, you can also try to deserialize our [XML files](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/tree/next/RubberduckTests/Testfiles/Resolver), and get all that information, too.

---

> Full disclosure: I'm heavily involved with the development of Rubberduck.

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the list from the listing at the left on [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj692811.aspx).

Comment: This is useful (+1) but perhaps OP is also looking for things such as `DMIN()` which are Access-specific rather than part of VBA per se.